# What is the meaning of nullable() in Laraval migration?

Tags: laravel, migration, nullable

What is the meaning of nullable() in Laraval migration?
For example, this is in our migration:

```php
$table->string('middle_name')->nullable();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means the `middle_name` field can also store null values: as in inserting a value is not required.

Imagine a registration form for example. Not everybody has a middle name. So in that case they would leave the `middle_name` field empty and in the database it'll be `null`.

Answer (score 1):

This is equivalent in MySQL statement "DEFAULT NULL", when we declare a column of a MySQL Table.

```
`imageURL` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
```

is equal to Laravel's

```
$table->string('imageURL',255)->nullable();
```

Then if it's default value is NULL, when we perform an INSERT statement without mentioning a value for that column, the value would be inserted as NULL.

Answer (score 0):

It will make the column nullable in the database which means you can store null values to that column or also can be said that it is not a mandatory field in database